# Error when setting keystore path to be relative

Tags: java, android

**What I need to happen:**
using a relative path for my keystore in my gradle to work.

**Things I have tried:**

`storeFile file('../keystore.jks')`

`storeFile file("$rootDir/keystore.jks")`

I have also tried it with not adding `.jks` at the end of the keystore name.  But I get the same error.  I am under the release variant.  I am using the Build APK option to build the APK.

**This is what my code looks like in my gradle:**

```
android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'key0'
        keyPassword 'testpassword'
        storeFile file('../keystore')
        storePassword 'testpassword'
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
   }
```

**This is the error I get:**

`Keystore file 'C:\Users\zzyzj\Documents\Android_Projects\EloterManResources\EloteMan\version\Udacity\eloteroMan\keystore' not found for signing config 'config'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use rootProject.file to access the keystore file. Something like this:

```
signingConfigs {
config {
    keyAlias 'key0'
    keyPassword 'testpassword'
    storeFile rootProject.file('keystore.jks')
    storePassword 'testpassword'
}
}
```

This is for the case when the keystore is in your root folder.If it's in some other folder give the correct relative path.